# How to call to function

Tags: java

I'm new in java.
I need to write a function that gets array A (The array size is n) and return true only if:

```
 A[x]>A[y]-10 (While 0≤x<n 0≤y<n  x≠y)
```

for example this array return true: `A={1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 3}`

Ok so here's my code, I'm trying to call the function "checkIfLargebyTen" but it doesn't work. what's wrong?

```
    package Ass2;

    public class Part0 {

            public static boolean forAllExists(int[] A) {
            boolean ans = true;
                for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++)
                {
                    if(checkIfLargebyTen(A,i)==false)
                    {
                        ans=false;
                    }//if
                }//for
            
                
//Boolean function that check if  A[x]>A[y]-10
           boolean checkIfLargebyTen(int[] arr, int x) {
              boolean ans=false;
                  for(int y=0; y<arr.length && ans==false; y++)
                   {
                    if (x!=y && arr[x]>arr[y]-10)
                    {
                        ans=true;
                    }//if
                }//for
                return ans;
            }//CheckFunction
                return ans;
            }//AllExixstsFunction
    }//class
```

Comment: Naming your package `Ass2` is not trivial thing to do.

Comment: why does it not work? or rather, what is going wrong?

Comment: it doesn't call the function at all.

Comment: @MarounMaroun just a shortcut of Assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you cannot define a method within a method. You should close the 'forAllExists`method before declaring the`checkIfLargeByTen` one:

```
public class Part0 {

        public static boolean forAllExists(int[] A) {
            boolean ans = true;
            for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++)
            {
                if(checkIfLargebyTen(A,i)==false)
                {
                    ans=false;
                }//if
            }//for

            return ans; // return missing in the OP
        } // close forAllExists - missing in the OP

       //Boolean function that check if  A[x]>A[y]-10
       static boolean checkIfLargebyTen(int[] arr, int x) {
          boolean ans=false;
              for(int y=0; y<arr.length && ans==false; y++)
               {
                if (x!=y && arr[x]>arr[y]-10)
                {
                    ans=true;
                }//if
            }//for
            return ans;
        }//CheckFunction
}//class
```

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it but it still gives me an error on row 7: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method checkIfLargebyTen(int[], int) from the type Part0

Comment: @user3075653 yup, didn't notice that. `checkIfLargebyTen` should be `static` too - see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I guess u meant static boolean... and not boolean static.

Comment: Sorry about the stupid Q but why the function must be static?

Comment: @user3075653 indeed, `static boolen`, fixed. It must be staic since it's called from a staic function - you can't call an instance function fom a stic function - what instance would it refer to?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could make function which goes through all the values with two for loops and as soon as some pair (x, y) does not fit your condition, return false. I think you are doing the same thing, but this is all in one method.

```
public static boolean checkSomething(int[] arr)
{
   for(int i = 0;i < arr.length;i ++)
   {
      for(int j = 0;j < arr.length;j ++)
      {
         if(arr[i]<=arr[j]-10) return false;
      }
   }

   return true;
}
```

Jesse.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I've not thought about this but good idea. I'll try it if my own code won't work.

Comment: If your goal is to check if there aren't numbers which are more than 10 apart, you could also run one for loop and store only the highest and lowest value. Then check if the condition returns true for those numbers. If so, it should for the whole array. This should be faster.